# Library to help convert a json library to pydantic type based off of string name of type that handles Unions and other complexity for me

Tags: library, python

I get back from a rest call a json response That should be a pydantic TaskResult which takes a generic type, and a description of the generic type for that TaskResult.  So in theory it should be easy to convert from json to pydantic.  Something like this:

```
generic_type = getattr(my_pydantic_types, type_name)
results = parse_obj_as(TaskResult[generic_type], data)
```

However I ran into a case where we had a Union(File, Directory) as our type.  The simple getattr approach doesn't handle Unions.  I could probably do it by hand, but it's uglier and I don't know if there are other pydantic meta-types I'll forget to handle - my general rule of thumb is if I'm considering doing regexs on a string for a task others often perform it's time to break out a library.

So, is there a simple library will convert my json, or even just look up a good type for me to run parse_obj_as with, that will take a string name of type and a module and look up things for me?